INVALID_ARGUMENT: You must feed a value for placeholder tensor 'conv2d_input' with dtype float and shape
I was trying to build a gradient heatmap model using the following code:
import tensorflow as tf
import tensorflow.keras.layers as klayers
import tensorflow.keras.models as kmodels
import tensorflow.keras.backend as kbackend
tf.compat.v1.disable_eager_execution()

model = ...(omitted)

neuron_indexing = klayers.Input(
    shape=(2,),  # infer amount of output neurons
    dtype=np.int32,
    name="neuron_indexing",
)
analysis_inputs = [neuron_indexing]
    
inputs = model.inputs + analysis_inputs
outputlist = model.outputs + [neuron_indexing]
X, index = outputlist
model_output = tf.gather_nd(X, index)
tmpmodel = kmodels.Model(inputs=inputs, outputs=model_output)
    
analysis_outputs = kbackend.gradients(tmpmodel.outputs[0], model.inputs)
outputs = analysis_outputs
analyzer_model = kmodels.Model(inputs=inputs,outputs=outputs)

and in the last line analyzer_model = kmodels.Model(inputs=inputs,outputs=outputs), I got the following error:
InvalidArgumentError: 2 root error(s) found.
  (0) INVALID_ARGUMENT: You must feed a value for placeholder tensor 'conv2d_input' with dtype float and shape [?,50,50,1]
     [[{{node conv2d_input}}]]
     [[gradients/zeros/Const/_265]]
  (1) INVALID_ARGUMENT: You must feed a value for placeholder tensor 'conv2d_input' with dtype float and shape [?,50,50,1]
     [[{{node conv2d_input}}]]
0 successful operations.
0 derived errors ignored.

my tensorflow version is 2.10.0, does anyone has any idea why is this happening?
I tried to switch the version, also tried with tf.gradients and tf.GradientTape(), the former gives same error, and the latter results in other errors.

I managed to achieve the same goal with another method, which is quite twisted and needs to load model weights every time. But it works. I put it up for reference, but I still don't know why the original code cannot work.
# make sure eager is disabled
def compute_grads(model, img, path):
    with tf.compat.v1.get_default_graph().as_default():
        img_input = tf.compat.v1.placeholder(dtype=tf.float32, shape=img_tensor.shape)
        output = model(img_input)
        loss = tf.reduce_sum(output)
        gradients = tf.gradients(ys=loss, xs=img_input)
        with tf.compat.v1.Session() as sess:
            sess.run(tf.compat.v1.global_variables_initializer())
            model.load_weights(path)
            gradient_values = sess.run(gradients, feed_dict={img_input: img})
        sess.close()
        return gradient_values[0]

